# Issue in assigning one calendar instance to another

Tags: java, android, calendar

I had two Calendar Instance variable, One declare globally and another one declare locally.
Now suppose i assign one calendar instance to another like

```
Calendar m_CalGlobally = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar calLocally = m_CalGlobally;
```

Now my issue is if i make any changes in calLocally variable, the same changes appear in m_CalGlobally instance variable, Why  this happen, and what is the way to assign this.

Answer (score 8):

Definitely That wont work.
Do like this

```
 Calendar m_CalGlobally = Calendar.getInstance();

 Calendar calLocally = (Calendar)m_CalGlobally.clone(); // Proper way to assign this.
//This will give you calender with same properties and also the changes of it wont be reflected on m_CalGlobally because assigning with equal operator make them point to same reference.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because both `m_CalGlobally`  and `calLocally` are references to the same (identical) object. To have them independent you need to create another instance of Calendar.
Assuming you have a typo in 2nd line (`Calendar calLocally = m_CalGlobally;`)